# Multi label dice similarity calculation: is there any issue?

Tags: caffe, image-segmentation, pycaffe

I am adding a function into this [online code](https://github.com/martinkersner/py_img_seg_eval) and wondering whether I am calculating `dsc` for each label correctly or not! I would appreciate if experts have a look at it and let me know if I am doing something wrong:

```
    #cl= list of class labels for exmple [0,1,2]
    for i, c in enumerate(cl):
            curr_eval_mask = eval_mask[i, :, :]
            curr_gt_mask = gt_mask[i, :, :]

            if (np.sum(curr_eval_mask) == 0) or (np.sum(curr_gt_mask) == 0):
                continue

            n_ii = np.sum(np.logical_and(curr_eval_mask, curr_gt_mask))
            t_i  = np.sum(curr_gt_mask)
            n_ij = np.sum(curr_eval_mask)

            DSC[i] =(2*n_ii) / (t_i + n_ij )
    mean_DSC_ = np.sum(DSC) / n_cl_gt
    #n_cl_gt=number of classes in ground truth
    where: n_cl : number of classes included in ground truth segmentation
n_ij : number of pixels of class i predicted to belong to class j
t_i : total number of pixels of class i in ground truth segmentation
```

My the other question is: Does `mean intersection over union (IoU)` is same as mean `Jaccard` and dice can be calculated `dice=(2*Jacc)/(1+Jacc)` as well?

I calculated mean dsc by the code for one image and is `0.01958`, however, mean Iou for the same image is `0.0101`, I am thinking I am doing some mistakes in somewhere. resources are mentioning that normally `Jacc` is always larger than `DSC`. By calculating according to the formula, i am obtaining `0.01999` for dice similarity. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure your `eval_mask` is binary? is it possible it has **continuous** values in the range `[0, 1]` and not just `{0, 1}`?

Comment: yes, extract_masks is  function that doing that in a for loop: `for i, c in enumerate(cl):   
        masks[i, :, :] = segm == c`

Comment: Dear Shai, is the main formulation correct? `DSC[i] =(2*n_ii) / (t_i + n_ij )`

Comment: AFAIK it is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help